# Skimage.io.imread giving confusing error

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm using skimage.io to read in images, but it isn't working for some images.

e.g. both file1 and file2 point to images within the same file, but were taken with different cameras.

```
img1 = io.imread(file1)
print(img)

img2 = io.imread(file2)
print(img)
```

img1 is what you expect (a numpy array of the rgb values) but img2 gives an error:

```
SystemError: <method-wrapper '__le__' of MpoImageFile object at 0x000001F480087630> returned a result with an error set
```

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this or how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: can you upload the file so that others can test and replicate the problem?